# What is the expected value of a R-S integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In this problem, we'll be looking at a Riemann-Stieltjes integral on $(-\infty, \infty)$. Suppose $X$ is a random vriable that takes on values $1,2,3$ with probabilities $1/4, 1/3, 5/12$ respectively. Let $F(x) =$ the probability $X \leq x$. Write a formula for $F(x)$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$. The expected value of $X$ is defined to be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x ~dF(x)$. Compute $E(X)$ by evaluating the integral.

So, $F(x)$ represents the CDF of $X$. Then, $F(x) = P(X\leq x) = \sum_{x_i\leq x} p(x_i)$. Over $(-\infty,\infty)$, this sum will converge to $1$ (starts at 0 and reaches 1 at $x=3$). Then, wouldn't the integral become $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x (1)$? I am a little confused as to how $F(x)$ plays in the integral. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, the function $F$ is piecewise constant and only has discrete jumps at the values $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. This means that at all other values of $x$ ($x\not \in \{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$), we have that $dF(x) = 0$, and at $x=x_i$, we have $dF(x) = F(x_i)-F(x_i-)$, where the expression $F(x_i-)$ is the left limit of $F$ at $x_i$.

So this means that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdF(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3x_i(F(x_i)-F(x_i-)).$$

Here we have, for instance, that $F(x_2)-F(x_2-) = (1/3+1/4) - 1/4 = 1/3$, so you can also realize that

$$\sum_{i=1}^3x_i(F(x_i)-F(x_i-)) = \sum_{i=1}^3x_ip(x_i),$$

which coincides with the usual expectation of a discrete variable.